# Can't get bluetooth installed on Kubuntu Kernel 5.8 - Tried so many things >.<

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have tried nearly everything I can think of to get bluetooth installed on Linux.

I've installed bluez, blueman, other things... I can never get a bluetooth service running.

```
systemctl status start bluetooth
Unit start.service could not be found.
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

May 18 14:29:45 mpaccione systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

I have no bluetooth menu in any GUI and have never been able to get one started. Also have never been able to get a modprobe btusb running or list any bluetooth controllers despite having a Avantree DG80 that should work with my Linux comp.

HALP!>

Currently installed packages:

```
bluetooth/groovy-updates,groovy-updates,now 5.55-0ubuntu1.1 all [installed]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/groovy,now 3.34.3-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-bluetooth/groovy,now 3.34.3-2 amd64 [installed]
indicator-bluetooth/groovy,now 0.0.6+17.10.20170605-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libbluetooth-dev/groovy-updates,now 5.55-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
libbluetooth3-dbg/groovy-updates,now 5.55-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libbluetooth3/groovy-updates,now 5.55-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-bluetooth13/groovy,now 3.34.3-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/groovy-updates,now 1:13.99.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed]
```

Here is a Gist of the log output for attempting to run systemctl start bluetooth:
https://gist.github.com/mpaccione/623ddacf0eb1a9c14d9d08ee65948337

Comment: FIrst, did you install  bluetooth? Type "apt list --installed | grep bluetooth". If it's installed, then  try "systemctl enable bluetooth". If that doesn't work, type "systemctl status bluetooth" and check the output of "journalctl -xe" .

Comment: And type "hciconfig -a" - is the device up?

Comment: @CinaedSimson Okay I updated the original post with some additional details regarding your comments!

Comment: Are you running this command: systemctl enable bluetooth as root?

Comment: @CinaedSimson Same result as root

Comment: Okay, you should try a Kubuntu mailing list - appears some things may be broken.

Comment: :( FATAL: Module btusb not found? Do I need this one lol?