# FATAL: Module btusb not found

Tags: kde, kernel-modules, bluetooth

I have never been able to get bluetooth working.

```
FATAL: Module btusb not found
```

I think I don't have the bluetooth driver "btusb"...

Can someone please advise me on how to install btusb, thank you.

```
System:
  Host: mpaccione Kernel: 5.8.0-53-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 10.2.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.19.5 Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: Z77-A v: Rev X.0x 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0402 
  date: 01/18/2013 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core Intel Core i7-3770 [MT MCP] arch: Ivy Bridge speed: 4225 MHz 
  min/max: 1600/4100 MHz 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics 
  vendor: ASUSTeK P8 series driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia 
  v: 450.119.03 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nvidia s-res: 5760x1080 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.119.03 
  direct render: Yes 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: ASUSTeK P8 series driver: r8169 v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  Device-2: BUFFALO (formerly Mel ) WLI-UC-GNM Wireless LAN Adapter [Ralink 
  RT8070] 
  type: USB driver: rt2800usb bus ID: 3-4:3 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 223.57 GiB used: 349.10 GiB (156.1%) 
Info:
  Processes: 371 Uptime: 1h 15m Memory: 15.52 GiB used: 5.41 GiB (34.9%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: 3022 Shell: Bash 
  v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.1.07
```

Comment: kde isn't a linux version, try showing inxi -bx, you have a kernel, you have a distribution, and on top of that, kde runs, it's  irrelevant re btusb. It's hard to find a distro that doesn't have btusb support out of the box, but apparently you found one. However, kde 5.8 is getting old, so that's not a good sign. Remember: distro + kernel is where your drivers live, not in your desktop, this isn't windows or osx.

Comment: Gotcha updated!

Comment: /lib/modules/5.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth has a bt_usb_bak file in it... I also have other versions in my modules folder of older 5.4 installs. Should I delete those? Would it break anything by chance?

Comment: Don't worry about those. If you start deleting random stuff without knowing why things rarely get better. Your real question is why btusb, which almost always ships with most major and minor distros, isn't there, or, alternately, it's there and something is reporting it as  missing. inxi -Jx shows all your usb devices and their drivers. I've done a lot of dev work on linux + bluetooth and have never seen the btusb driver missing, it certainly would not be missing from ubuntu. so it's either there, which you'll see with inxi -Jx, or something made it go away. The _bak files are odd.

Comment: Yeah something is wierd man I have never been able to get bluetooth working and Ive shipped too many dongles back now to get to this point with the drivers...this appears to be the usb dongle I have now from the above post: type: USB driver: rt2800usb bus ID: 3-4:3  also I have more information here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650325/cant-get-bluetooth-installed-on-kubuntu-kernel-5-8-tried-so-many-things I don't have enough linux wizardy man :*(

Comment: Enable service, then start it. That has nothing to do with btusb being missing, if it is, that was caused by an action you probably took, if it's not, it's not missing, so that's not relevant to your overall  question.

Comment: Okay I've never been able to start the service :shrug:

Comment: Unfortunately you are using a legacy version of inxi, the current version does a much better job of trying to diagnose bluetooth issues. Do it one step at a  time, don't go to the next step until the previous step worked. Don't feel bad, the  online linux docs and instructions for bluetooth are absolutely terrible, lol.